# TTTAttributedLabel: Wrong text rendering for \r\n line ending

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text

In `TTTAttributedLabel`, `\r\n` is counted as 2 line endings while it should be only one. UILabel handle this case correctly.

Example: This is the string `@"Line 1\r\nLine 2"`. The top one is `TTTAttributedLabel`, bottom one is `UILabel`

[image: TTTAttributedLabel vs UILabel]

Xcode project file: http://tinywhale.net/TestProject.zip

Any idea how to make TTTAttributedLabel behaves like UILabel in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you know exactly what's the problem. I am also with you, I suffered the same reason.
for a almost two weeks i tried out  to solve the problem. 
Googling and looking Apple's documentation and  looking the stackoverflow, I've looked everywhere, could not get a clear answer. 
In UILabel property "text(NSString)" is \ r \ n and comes up with two consecutive \ n applies only. but CustomLabel property "attributedText(NSAttributedString)" is \ r \ n When both are applied successively.So my solution \ r \ n and occurrence of two consecutive \ r has been replaced with a null string.

```
NSString *string = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithString:string];
```

In fact, @ "Line 1 \ r \ n Line 2" If you check the NSLog have interesting facts.

```
NSLog(@"Line 1\r\nLine 2");
```

**In Simulator**

```
2012-08-05 23:18:59.170 SimpleTest[30721:707] Line 1
Line 2
```

**In Device**

```
2012-08-05 23:18:59.170 SimpleTest[30721:707] Line 1

Line 2
```

As you can see above, the simulator and the device \ r's processing is different. For this reason, I did a whole lot of effort.I do not know exactly what, armv7 and this is about the difference between i386 processing. but i think
if a bug or a kind of NSString and NSAttributedString also think that these relationships.

My answer to solve your problem I really hope it might help to you.

Comment: Removing \r with an empty string would be the last option for me as I need to maintain the string's length for some reason. I have opened an issue on TTTAttributedLabel's repo on github, you can subscribe to this to see if there's any update from @mattt, who should know more about CoreText: https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/issues/116